# Autogenerating BigQuery schema from python dictionary

Tags: python, google-bigquery

How do you autogenerate a BigQuery table schema from a python dictionary?

E.g.

```
dict = {'data': 'some_data', 'me': 8}
schema = BigQuery.generateSchema(dict)

#schema is now:
# {'fields': [
#    {'name': 'data', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
#    {'name': 'me', 'type': 'INT', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
# ]}
```

Does something like this exist?

Comment: As an update. I am quite sure this isn't possibly without some third party plugin. It seems we will have to write the code ourselves!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment there is no current way to do this from the BigQuery Python library.

Here is a recursive function to achieve it.

```py
import datetime
from google.cloud.bigquery.schema import SchemaField

# [START] map_dict_to_bq_schema

# FieldType Map Dictionary
field_type = {
        str: 'STRING',
        bytes: 'BYTES',
        int: 'INTEGER',
        float: 'FLOAT',
        bool: 'BOOLEAN',
        datetime.datetime: 'DATETIME',
        datetime.date: 'DATE',
        datetime.time: 'TIME',
        dict: 'RECORD',
}


# Function to take a dictionary
# and return a bigquery schema
def map_dict_to_bq_schema(source_dict):

    # SchemaField list
    schema = []

    # Iterate the existing dictionary
    for key, value in source_dict.items():

        try:
            schemaField = SchemaField(key, field_type[type(value)]) # NULLABLE BY DEFAULT
        except KeyError:

            # We are expecting a REPEATED field
            if value and len(value) > 0:
                schemaField = SchemaField(key, field_type[type(value[0])], mode='REPEATED') # REPEATED

        # Add the field to the list of fields
        schema.append(schemaField)

        # If it is a STRUCT / RECORD field we start the recursion
        if schemaField.field_type == 'RECORD':

            schemaField._fields = map_dict_to_bq_schema(value)

    # Return the dictionary values
    return schema

# [END] map_dict_to_bq_schema
```

Example:

```py
>>> map_dict_to_bq_schema({'data': 'some_data', 'me': 8})
# Output
>>> [SchemaField('data', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField('me', 'INTEGER', 'NULLABLE', None, ())]


>>> map_dict_to_bq_schema({'data': {'data2': 'some_data', 'me2': 8}, 'me': 8, 'h':[5,6,7]})
# Output
>>> [SchemaField('h', 'INTEGER', 'REPEATED', None, ()), SchemaField('me', 'INTEGER', 'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField('data', 'RECORD', 'NULLABLE', None, [SchemaField('data2', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, ()), SchemaField('me2', 'INTEGER', 'NULLABLE', None, ())])]
```

I used the code by @luckylwk in this question as a reference: [How to map a Python Dict to a Big Query Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705005/how-to-map-a-python-dict-to-a-big-query-schema), specially for the [nested and repeated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#specifying_nested_and_repeated_columns) columns.

Also, check the [SchemaField](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField.html#google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField) class from the BQ python library. From there you can get the format you want to use the schema with the python client, CLI or the one that matches your use case.

Comment: +9000 works better than bigquery_schema_generator in Python, thanks